# Prevent Magento setup resources from running automatically

Tags: magento-1.9, setup-script

What is the setting within `app/etc/local.xml` to prevent setup resources from being triggered to run automatically?

I have seen this somewhere but cannot locate it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually tracked down where I had seen this on the [Inchoo blog](http://inchoo.net/magento/taking-control-over-module-upgrade-process/).

These are the two configuration settings needed within `app/etc/local.xml` to disable the automatic processing of setup resources:

```
<skip_process_modules_updates>1</skip_process_modules_updates>
<skip_process_modules_updates_ignore_dev_mode>1</skip_process_modules_updates_ignore_dev_mode>
```

You can then manually trigger the updates using `n98-magerun sys:setup:incremental` assuming that you have n98-magerun installed/available.

Reference: [Inchoo - 
Taking control over module upgrade process](http://inchoo.net/magento/taking-control-over-module-upgrade-process/)